# How do I make interact point-free?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

```
shortLinesOnly :: IO ()
shortLinesOnly = interact result
    where
        shortLength     = 11
        onlyShorts      = (<= shortLength) . length
        shortLines      = filter onlyShorts . lines
        result          = unlines . shortLines
        interact result = getContents >>= putStr . result
```

In the above code how can I write the *interact* function in point free style.

Comment: Isn't `interact` already in prelude?

Comment: @Tinctorius in the shortLinesOnly function interact is not point free.  A point free function never mentions the actual arguments.  The interact function mentions result.

Comment: @delnan you are correct.  The interact is already in prelude.  I am coming up with my own implementation to understand Haskell better.

Comment: I believe [Lambdabot](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lambdabot) can make things point free.

Comment: Just a note; there's a [command-line package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) that will do this sort of thing for you. If you install it and enter `pointfree "interact result = getContents >>= putStr . result"` in the terminal it will return `interact = (getContents >>=) . (putStr .)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Step by step:

```
interact r = getContents >>= putStr . r
interact r = (getContents >>=) (putStr . r)
interact r = (getContents >>=) $ (putStr .) $ r
interact = (getContents >>=) . (putStr .)
```

Comment: The step by step really helps.

Answer (score 6):

The best answer is:  Don't.  For this particular example the only change that would make is that your code would be less readable.  Your original pointy variant is perfectly fine.

In certain cases it is better to avoid pointfree style.  This is one of them, because your argument does not undergo linear data flow.  It is rather used to build the data flow for something else.  Example:

```
-- Bad: Pointy linear data flow description.
chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf n xs =
    takeWhile (not . null) (map (take n) (iterate (drop n) xs))

-- Good: Pointfree linear data flow description.
chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf n =
    takeWhile (not . null) . map (take n) . iterate (drop n)

-- Bad: Now exaggerating with pointfree style.
chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf =
    liftA2 ((.) (.) . (.) $ takeWhile (not . null))
           (map . take)
           (iterate . drop)
```

Comment: you are right point free style is harder to read in this case.  I just wanted to know how to do it.